# Get working path of xml file

Tags: spring-mvc

Let me describe my situation like following:
I have created my spring-mvc webapplication with structure like this:

```
-Trainingapp
    -Java Resources
        -src/test/java
        -src/test/resources
        -src/main/java
            -com.example.controller
            -com.example.dao
                -ReadAttributesService.java
            -com.example.ctx
                -AppContext.java
            -com.example.pojos
        -src/main/resources
            -META-INF
                -applicationContext.xml
            settings.xml
```

ReadAttributesService's constructor takes a filePath parameter to parse from settings.xml into an XMLBeans. I want the application to create a bean of ReadAttributesService so i put this to my applicationContext.xml file

```
<!-- ReadAttributesService bean -->
<bean id="readAttributesService" class="com.example.dao.ReadAttributesService">
    <constructor-arg name="filePath" value="src/main/resources/settings.xml" />
</bean>
```

Ok whatever the value of filePath i gave to the applicationContext was not going to work, atleast with what i've done. In the end, i want to create a new FileInputStream of settings.xml but i haven't found any way to accomplish this.

So to put this simple, i want to ask how can i create a FileInputStream or something like an AbsolutePath of settings.xml in my spring-mvc webapplication?
Thank you in advanced, any help is really appriciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need a `InputStream` (as opposed to a `FileInputStream`), since `settings.xml` should be on your classpath, I would try using [Spring Resources](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/resources.html). Your XML bean declaration should look something like this:

```
<!-- ReadAttributesService bean -->
<bean id="readAttributesService" class="com.example.dao.ReadAttributesService">
   <constructor-arg name="settings" value="settings.xml" />
</bean>
```

With the constructor arg of `ReadAttributesService` like:

```
public class ReadAttributesService {

    public ReadAttributesService(org.springframework.core.io.Resource settings){
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Spring will automatically convert the `settings.xml` string into the `Resource` (which will actually be a `ClassPathResource`).

From there you should be able to call the `getInputStream()` method on that resource.

If you really do need a `FileInputStream`, it gets tricky.

Comment: No, Resource and ClassPathResource are enough :D Thank you!